# Get penultimate element MongoDB

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

Is there are way to identify the penultimate object in a MongoDB collection?

I get the last one with:

```
collection.find({}, {sort: {Date: -1}}).fetch();
```

But how can I get the penultimate one?

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `limit` and `skip` here

`collection.find({}, {sort: {Date: -1}, limit:1}).fetch();` will give you the last record, and

`collection.find({}, {sort: {Date: -1}, limit:1, skip:1}).fetch();` gives you the penultimate record